# div analog for a responsive column table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to accomplish same result of a table like the following using divs so I can make it responsive and adjust how many columns for each table row.  (for instance, On first row there are 3 responsive columns, then on row two there are four responsive columns). I Also want to avoid writing single word in a separate tr

Is there a way to do it?

here is current table

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="short-column">Short Column</th> <!-- th sets the width -->
            <th class="short-column">Short Column</th> <!-- th sets the width -->
            <th class="long-column">Long Column</th> <!-- th sets the width -->
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="lite-gray">Short Column</td> <!-- td inherits th width -->
            <td class="lite-gray">Short Column</td> <!-- td inherits th width -->
            <td class="gray">Long Column</td> <!-- td inherits th width -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


table { table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%; }

.short-column { background: yellow; width: 30%; }
.long-column { background: lime; width: 40%; }

.lite-gray { background: #f2f2f2; }
.gray { background: #cccccc; }
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKAj8/)

Is it possible to use something like

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
          <tr>
         <td>
                 <!--<div>THREE COLUMNS</div>-->
             </td>
         </tr>  
          <tr>
         <td>
                 <!--<div>FOUR COLUMNS?</div>-->
             </td>
         </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/TdmkG/1/

Comment: Yes, exactly what needed. Could you please post the code here, so I can accept your answer, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insert floated divs into your td elements, you can create the same layout:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--<div>THREE COLUMNS</div>-->
            <div class="three"></div>
            <div class="three"></div>
            <div class="half"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--<div>FOUR COLUMNS?</div>-->
            <div class="four"></div>
            <div class="four"></div>
            <div class="four"></div>
            <div class="four"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then just add some styles for the widths and you're all set!

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TdmkG/1/